# Kettle Execute for every n row

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

In a job, you can have a transformation in the flow and have it set to execute for every one row.

Is there a way to have the transformation execute for every n rows?

I want to be able to pass a batch of n rows to a transformation.

What is the best (any, really) way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Let your job call transformation A which will act as a parent/controller, and have transformation A call transformation B using a Transformation Executor step.  In this step you can specify the number of rows to pass to transformation B each time under the 'Row grouping' tab as shown.

Your inner transformation (B) will need to start with a step that can receive the rows from A; I have used a 'Get rows from result' step to accomplish this in some of my work.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It is possible.
When you select transformation inside job just open the transformation properties. 
There you will find very first option called Execute every input row, by default it will be disable, just enable it. It will work. [image]

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I'm aware of this. My ask was for a way of executing for >1 rows. Thanks anyway.

Comment: As per my knowledge N row execution option is not available.